# Some services are not able to be constructed in a AuthorizationHandler

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Consider the following

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AccountHandler>();
...
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, IsOwnerHandler>();
```

Now my initialize container

```
private void InitializeContainer()
{
  container.Register(typeof(ICommandAsyncHandler<>), typeof(ICommandAsyncHandler<>).Assembly);
  container.Register(typeof(IQueryAsyncHandler<,>), typeof(IQueryAsyncHandler<,>).Assembly);
  container.Register(typeof(IValidationHandler<>), typeof(IValidationAsyncHandler<>).Assembly);

  container.Register<IMediator, Mediator>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
  ...
}
```

and the handler for `IsOwner`

```
public class IsOwnerHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IsOwnerRequirement>
{
  private readonly IMediator mediator;

  protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
     IsOwnerRequirement requirement)
  {
    ...
    context.Succeed(requirement);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }

  public IsOwnerHandler(IMediator mediator)
  {
    this.mediator = mediator;
  }
}
```

the wireup class

```
private void IntegrateSimpleInjector(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
    {
        options.AddAspNetCore()
            .AddControllerActivation()
            .AddViewComponentActivation()
            .AddPageModelActivation()
            .AddTagHelperActivation();
        options.AddLogging();
    });
}
```

I am running into the following error when the application starts

`AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationHandler Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: LM3.NNB.Gateway.WebSite.Infrastructure.Authorisation.IsOwnerHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'LM3.NNB.Gateway.WebSite.Infrastructure.Mediator.IMediator' while attempting to activate 'LM3.NNB.Gateway.WebSite.Infrastructure.Authorisation.IsOwnerHandler'.)`

I am trying to get a instance of `mediator` from within the handler. I can only assume that `IMediator` is not being registered withn the `services` and therefore is causing the issue. So I suspect I have not wired this up correctly.

Just in case this is needed IsOwnerHandler is an attribute on `[Authorize(Policy = nameof(Policy.IsOwner))]` on a razor page

The wireup for authorization is

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    ...
    options.AddPolicy(nameof(Policy.IsOwner),
       policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new IsOwnerRequirement()));
});
```

Comment: Why are you registering `IsOwnerHandler` in MS.DI instead of Simple Injector? If you register `IsOwnerHandler` in Simple Injector the problem likely goes away because you registered `IMediator` in Simple Injector; not in MS.DI.

Comment: @Steven yes I did try that, the applciation starts up. However what I am finding is that the `IsOwnerHandler` is not getting fired. The attribute is on a razor page `[Authorize(Policy = nameof(Policy.IsOwner))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler>(
    _ => container.GetInstance<IsOwnerHandler>());

container.Register<IsOwnerHandler>();
```

Comment: Bingo, perfect! Thanks Steven, assume this helps both .NET DI and Simple Injector to play together for this example